# file encryption and decryption c# Rijndael cipher

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, encryption, rijndael

I can encrypt a text file that is located on my desktop using the following code.

```
 private void btnEncrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //EncryptFile(); 
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            dialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|";
            dialog.InitialDirectory = @"Desktop";
            dialog.Title = "Please select a file to encrypt.";

            dialog.ShowDialog();

            inputFile = dialog.FileName;

            outputFile = inputFile;

            string password = @"myKey123"; // Your Key Here
            UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
            byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password);

            string cryptFile = outputFile;
            FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(cryptFile, FileMode.Create);

            RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt,
                RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, key),
                CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

            int data;
            while ((data = fsIn.ReadByte()) != -1)
                cs.WriteByte((byte)data);


            fsIn.Close();
            cs.Close();
            fsCrypt.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

this works great but when i try to decrypt the same text file nothing happens, no error message is thrown to let me know what is going on, i use the following code for decryption

```
private void btnDecrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            dialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|";
            dialog.InitialDirectory = @"Desktop";
            dialog.Title = "Please select a file to decrypt.";

            dialog.ShowDialog();

            inputFile = dialog.FileName; // "C:\\Users\\daniel\\Desktop\\text.txt";
            outputFile = inputFile;


                string password = @"myKey123"; // Your Key Here

                UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
                byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password);

                FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);

                RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

                CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt,
                    RMCrypto.CreateDecryptor(key, key),
                    CryptoStreamMode.Read);

                FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

                int data;
                while ((data = cs.ReadByte()) != -1)
                    fsOut.WriteByte((byte)data);

                fsOut.Close();
                cs.Close();
                fsCrypt.Close();

            }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        }
    }
```

can anybody help?

Comment: In this case "works great" means "runs but is utterly insecure".

Comment: Does it decrypt when `outputFile != inputFile`?

Comment: This is a follow up for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647456/rijndael-cipher-error-in-c-sharp-windows-form

Comment: Hi @CodesInChaos I know it's not secure, its just a starting point for me but cheers for the input

Answer (score 0):

`fsOut` is open as a read-only stream.  Try this instead.

```
 FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(
       outputFile, 
       FileMode.Open, 
       FileAccess.Write, 
       FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

*Note*:  I would also write to a temp file and copy over the original when completed but I don't have a *great* reason for it.

Comment: Hi Austin, I'll try this later as I don't have my laptop with me and I'll let u know how I get on